# Spring MVC loses my session state when allowing user to upload 2 files in different steps on the form

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, file-upload, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a form that allows a user to enter a couple of fields and upload two separate files.  As each file is uploaded, a request is sent to the server to retrieve the file and build the display.  Once the user is satisfied that the display looks good, they can commit the new data to the database.

The problem I am having I that Spring-MVC seems to lose the session object on the last call to the server.  I need it to retain the session until I specifically tell it to drop the objects using the SessionStatus.

Here is the code for my controller class:

```
package com.mbn.modeldisplay.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.mbn.modeldisplay.pojo.CandidateModel;
import com.mbn.modeldisplay.pojo.Model;
import com.mbn.modeldisplay.service.IModelService;
import com.mbn.modeldisplay.service.ServiceException;
import com.mbn.modeldisplay.util.TempFileManager;

@SessionAttributes(value = { "candidateModel" })
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/model/*")
public class ModelHandler {

    protected static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ModelHandler.class);
    protected IModelService modelService = null;

    private static final String DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_TEXTURE = "/assets/defaultimage.png";
    private static final String CANDIDATE_MODEL_NAME = "candidateModel";

    @ModelAttribute(CANDIDATE_MODEL_NAME)
    public CandidateModel createCandidate() {
        CandidateModel candidate = new CandidateModel();
        log.debug("createCandidate returning: " + candidate);
        log.debug("\n\n");
        return candidate;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String startEditModel(
            @RequestParam(value = "modelId", required = false) String modelId,
            @ModelAttribute CandidateModel candidate) {

        try {
            Model m = modelService.read(modelId);
            if (null == m) {
                m = new Model();
                m.modelId = modelId;
            }

            candidate.setOriginal(m);
            log.debug("startEditModel returning: " + candidate);
        } catch (ServiceException se) {
            log.error("Unable to access datastore", se);
        }
        log.debug("\n\n");
        return "ModelEdit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "register/binary", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addModel(@RequestParam MultipartFile model,
            @ModelAttribute(CANDIDATE_MODEL_NAME) CandidateModel tempCandidate) {

        log.debug("addModel received: " + tempCandidate);
        try {
            File tempFile = tempCandidate.getCandidateModelFile();
            if (null != tempFile) {
                log.debug("Remove previous candidate: "
                        + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
                tempFile.delete();
            }

            tempFile = TempFileManager.getTempFile(
                    "norrim01",
                    "ModelDisplay",
                    model.getOriginalFilename().substring(
                            model.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf('.')));
            log.debug("Writing to temp file: " + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());

            InputStream is = model.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int read;
            while (-1 != (read = is.read(buffer))) {
                fw.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            fw.flush();
            fw.close();

            tempCandidate.setCandidateModelFile(tempFile);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unable to process model file candidate.", e);

            return "ErrorPage";
        }
        log.debug("\n\n");
        return "ModelEdit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "register/binary", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getCandidateModel(HttpServletResponse response,
            @ModelAttribute(CANDIDATE_MODEL_NAME) CandidateModel tempCandidate)
            throws Exception {
        log.debug("getCandidateModel received: " + tempCandidate);

        File tempFile = tempCandidate.getCandidateModelFile();
        if (null == tempFile || !tempFile.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Candidate Model File");
        }

        log.debug("register/binary returning " + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());

        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader(
                "Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=candidatemodel"
                        + tempFile.getName().substring(
                                tempFile.getName().lastIndexOf('.')));

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
        OutputStream fw = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int read;
        while (-1 != (read = is.read(buffer))) {
            fw.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        log.debug("\n\n");
        fw.flush();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "register/template", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addTemplate(@RequestParam MultipartFile template,
            @ModelAttribute(CANDIDATE_MODEL_NAME) CandidateModel tempCandidate)
        throws Exception {
        log.debug("addTemplate received: " + tempCandidate);
        try {
            File tempFile = tempCandidate.getCandidateTemplateFile();
            if (null != tempFile) {
                log.debug("Remove previous candidate: "
                        + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
                tempFile.delete();
            }

            tempFile = TempFileManager.getTempFile(
                    "norrim01",
                    "ModelDisplay",
                    template.getOriginalFilename().substring(
                            template.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf('.')));
            log.debug("Writing to temp file: " + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());

            InputStream is = template.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int read;
            while (-1 != (read = is.read(buffer))) {
                fw.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            fw.flush();
            fw.close();

            tempCandidate.setCandidateTemplateFile(tempFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unable to process model file candidate.", e);

            return "ErrorPage";
        }
        log.debug("\n\n");

        return "ModelEdit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "register/template", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getCandidateTemplate(
            @ModelAttribute(CANDIDATE_MODEL_NAME) CandidateModel tempCandidate,
            HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        log.debug("getCandidateTemplate received: " + tempCandidate);
        File tempFile = tempCandidate.getCandidateTemplateFile();
        log.debug("register/template found in session: " + tempFile);
        if (null == tempFile || !tempFile.exists()) {
            String location = session.getServletContext().getRealPath(
                    DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_TEXTURE);
            if (null != location)
                tempFile = new File(location);
            else
                throw new FileNotFoundException(
                        "Unable to locate the default template texture");
        }

        log.debug("register/template returning " + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());

        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader(
                "Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=candidatetemplate"
                        + tempFile.getName().substring(
                                tempFile.getName().lastIndexOf('.')));

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
        OutputStream fw = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int read;
        while (-1 != (read = is.read(buffer))) {
            fw.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        fw.flush();

        log.debug("\n\n");
    }

    /**
     * @return the modelService
     */
    public IModelService getModelService() {
        return modelService;
    }

    /**
     * @param modelService
     *            the modelService to set
     */
    @Autowired
    public void setModelService(IModelService modelService) {
        this.modelService = modelService;
    }

}
```

The model file is uploaded and is correctly retrieved using a GET request to the same URL, and the graphic file is also correctly uploaded to the `/register/template` URL and added to the candidateModel session object, but when the `register/template` GET is issued, Spring-MVC creates a new, empty CandidateModel object and I cannot retrieve the uploaded graphic, as seen from the debug output, here:

```
2013-09-11 11:58:10,078 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] addModel received: CandidateModel [original=null, candidateModelFile=null, candidateTemplateFile=null, object Id=com.mbn.modeldisplay.pojo.CandidateModel@1c6cc9c] 
2013-09-11 11:58:10,216 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] Writing to temp file: C:\Users\Michael Norris\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\temp\norrim011291263503728127085.obj 
2013-09-11 11:58:10,221 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] 


2013-09-11 11:58:10,398 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] getCandidateModel received: CandidateModel [original=null, candidateModelFile=C:\Users\Michael Norris\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\temp\norrim011291263503728127085.obj, candidateTemplateFile=null, object Id=com.mbn.modeldisplay.pojo.CandidateModel@1c6cc9c] 
2013-09-11 11:58:10,398 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] register/binary returning C:\Users\Michael Norris\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\temp\norrim011291263503728127085.obj 
2013-09-11 11:58:10,400 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] 


2013-09-11 11:58:10,460 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] createCandidate returning: CandidateModel [original=null, candidateModelFile=null, candidateTemplateFile=null, object Id=com.mbn.modeldisplay.pojo.CandidateModel@3c7038b9] 
2013-09-11 11:58:10,460 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] 


2013-09-11 11:58:10,463 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] getCandidateTemplate received: CandidateModel [original=null, candidateModelFile=null, candidateTemplateFile=null, object Id=com.mbn.modeldisplay.pojo.CandidateModel@3c7038b9] 
2013-09-11 11:58:10,463 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] register/template found in session: null 
2013-09-11 11:58:10,464 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] register/template returning C:\Users\Michael Norris\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\webapps\ModelDisplay\assets\defaultimage.png 
2013-09-11 11:58:10,465 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] 


2013-09-11 11:58:15,426 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] addTemplate received: CandidateModel [original=null, candidateModelFile=C:\Users\Michael Norris\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\temp\norrim011291263503728127085.obj, candidateTemplateFile=null, object Id=com.mbn.modeldisplay.pojo.CandidateModel@1c6cc9c] 
2013-09-11 11:58:15,604 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] Writing to temp file: C:\Users\Michael Norris\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\temp\norrim01647051706271088553.PNG 
2013-09-11 11:58:15,986 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] 


2013-09-11 11:58:16,014 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] getCandidateModel received: CandidateModel [original=null, candidateModelFile=C:\Users\Michael Norris\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\temp\norrim011291263503728127085.obj, candidateTemplateFile=C:\Users\Michael Norris\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\temp\norrim01647051706271088553.PNG, object Id=com.mbn.modeldisplay.pojo.CandidateModel@1c6cc9c] 
2013-09-11 11:58:16,015 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] register/binary returning C:\Users\Michael Norris\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\temp\norrim011291263503728127085.obj 
2013-09-11 11:58:16,016 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] 


2013-09-11 11:58:16,117 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] createCandidate returning: CandidateModel [original=null, candidateModelFile=null, candidateTemplateFile=null, object Id=com.mbn.modeldisplay.pojo.CandidateModel@1ae73783] 
2013-09-11 11:58:16,118 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] 


2013-09-11 11:58:16,119 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] getCandidateTemplate received: CandidateModel [original=null, candidateModelFile=null, candidateTemplateFile=null, object Id=com.mbn.modeldisplay.pojo.CandidateModel@1ae73783] 
2013-09-11 11:58:16,119 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] register/template found in session: null 
2013-09-11 11:58:16,119 DEBUG  [ModelHandler] register/template returning C:\Users\Michael Norris\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\webapps\ModelDisplay\assets\defaultimage.png 
2013-09-11 11:58:16,121 DEBUG  [ModelHandler]
```

My view is using JQuery and Ajax to send the file as soon as it is selected.  On a successful result, `showCandidateModel` queries the server to retrieve the files using routines from THREE.js.  Here is an example of the upload that happens immediately upon choosing a file:

```
if (formdata) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ModelDisplay/rest/model/register/binary",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    showCandidateModel(); 
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = 
                        "<h2>" + textStatus + "</h2><BR><BR><p>" + errorThrown + "<p>"; 
                }
            });
        }
```

I have also tried adding `HttpSession` object to the handler methods and interacting with it directly using `addAttribute` and `getAttribute`, but it exhibits the same behavior, leading me to believe the Spring-MVC does not actually use a real session object from Tomcat, but some other implementation that it manages.

For completeness, here is my Spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


  <!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet -->
  <bean id="mongoDBDatabaseName" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="ModelDisplay"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="mongoDBDatabaseHost" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="localhost"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="mongoDBDatabasePort" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <constructor-arg value="27017"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="mongoDB" class="com.mbn.modeldisplay.dao.ModelDisplayMongoDB">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDBDatabaseName"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDBDatabaseHost"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDBDatabasePort"/>
  </bean>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.mbn.modeldisplay"/>

  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
      <property name="prefix" value="/"></property>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>        
  </bean>

  <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
      <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
      <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is my dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I have searched for examples and I have found many that show an upload of a single file, and multiple file upload examples, but none that provide for the uploading of multiple files in more than one step.  Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Have you checked in a proxy or with a browser dev tool that your ajax calls actually include a valid session cookie?  Tomcat 7 marks them to be suppressed by default iirc.

Comment: Thank you, Affe, I can see that the call to GET /register/binary sends the JSESSIONID cookie, but the call to GET /register/template does not.  I look at the JavaScript code and I do not see any difference in how the call is executed, except for the URL.  Do you know how I can force it to send the cookie?

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Session_cookie_configuration  ?

Comment: Upon further examination, I see now that the cookie is only not being passed on this line in the JavaScript: `var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('rest/model/register/template');`.  Under the covers, it's creating a new Image and setting its source to the given URL.  That is what is neglecting to send the JSESSIONID cookie.

Comment: I tried the different settings in the link that you provided to no avail.  I have gotten past the problem for now by using and Ajax call (which correctly sends the JSESSIONID cookie) to retrieve a base64-encoded version of the graphic and manually assigning it to the image's source attribute.  I am hopeful that there is a better solution to force the img object to send the cookie when I set its source property.  Thanks Affe, for your input.